# Help finding a good book on Finsler geometry

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

I want to learn more about Finsler geometry. I have just studying the book "An Introduction to Riemann-Finsler Geometry" by Bao, Chern and Shen, but i would like to study Finsler Geometry approach to fiber bundles, specifically sphere bundle.

I have been reading the book "initiation to global finslerian geometry" by Akbar-Zadeh, But I find that it is hard for me to underestand it. Is there any references with the same topics which can help me in better underestanding?

Thank you much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in applications of physics of methods of Finsler geometry, you can go to arXiv.org and/or inspirehep.net and give a search on my name: Vacaru,

or follow the links

http://inspirehep.net/search?ln=en&ln=en&p=find+a+Vacaru&action_search=Search&sf=&so=d&rm=&rg=100&sc=0&of=hb

http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all:+Vacaru/0/1/0/all/0/1

You shall find 3 monographs there, a series of reviews and many articles.

Good luck.

Sergiu Vacaru